# Does JavaScript allow Set keys for Objects fields?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

When I run the following code:

```
fake_key = new Set([{v: 1, w: 2}])
fake_memo = {};
fake_memo[fake_key] = 2;

fake_key = new Set([{v: 5, w: 5}])
fake_memo[fake_key] = 5;
```

And then print or log `fake_memo`, I expect to see:

```
{ '[object Set]': 2, '[object Set]': 5 }
```

Instead I get:

```
{ '[object Set]': 5 }
```

As if the first object I inserted into the object map got clobbered by the second.

Why does this occur? How do I recover the behavior I want (both keys being inserted into the map)?

Comment: objects have strings as keys. the set is converted to string, which is `'[object Set]'`.

Comment: Use a Map for that. In JS object keys are also strings, no exception, js objects are not hashmaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property keys of plain objects are always strings. Your sets are being converted to strings, which always gives the string `"[object Set]"`.

You can instead use a Map instance instead of a plain object, because Map keys can be any type of value. To do that, make a map:

```
fake_memo = new Map();
```

then

```
fake_memo.set(fake_key, 2);
```

etc. Use

```
var value = fake_memo.get(some_key);
```

to retrieve values.

You can use ordinary `[ ]` operations on a Map instance, but that will still treat the Map as an ordinary object.

Comment: The behavior is unchanged if I change to `fake_memo = new Map();`, unfortunately. More specifically, I now see `Map { '[object Set]': 5 }`.

Comment: Ah well you have to use the Map API to set and get values by key; I'll extend the answer.

Comment: So `Map.set` and `Map.get` differ in behavior from `Map[accessor] = foo`? [Wat?](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: @AlekseyBilogur yes, which is disturbing. You could use the Proxy feature to work around that, but depending on your point of view that might be more confusing than the default behavior. I haven't done a lot of work with either Set or Map so my opinion isn't worth much on that :)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it's clearly the correct one, but what a gotcha this API is!

Answer (score 1):

As another answer said, keys can only be strings. So this may be what you are looking for:

```
fake_key = JSON.stringify(Array.from(new Set([{v: 1, w: 2}])));
fake_memo = {};
fake_memo[fake_key] = 2;

fake_key = JSON.stringify(Array.from(new Set([{v: 5, w: 5}])));
fake_memo[fake_key] = 5;
```